# $h \circ g $ is 1-1 and onto $g$ is 1-1 and onto $h$ is onto - how to prove that $h$ is 1-1 too?

Tags: functions, proof-writing

$h \circ g $ is 1-1 and onto

$g$ is 1-1 and onto

$h$ is onto

I am trying to prove that $h$ is 1-1 too.

$h \circ g(x1) $ =$h \circ g(x2) \rightarrow  x1=x2 $   And due to the fact that $g$ is onto, therefore h is 1-1 too.

I can not find the way to write "And due to the fact that $g$ is onto, therefore h is 1-1 too." in a formal way.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Let $h(x_1)=h(x_2)$. Pick $y_1$ such that $g(y_1)=x_1$. Pick $y_2$ such that $g(y_2)=x_2$. Then, what can you say about $h(g(y_1))$ and $h(g(y_2))$?

Comment: Because $g$ is 1-1 $h(g(y1))=h(g(y2))$ ?

Comment: @gbox Because $g(y_1)=x_1$, we have $h(g(y_1))=h(?)$?

Comment: $x1=x2$ and therefore $h(x1)=h(x2)$?

Comment: @gbox Why is $x_1=x_2$? That is what you have to prove.... Again, if $g(y_1)=x_1$ what is $f(g(x_1))$?

Comment: $h(g(y1))=h(g(y2))$ because it is 1-1 and therefore $x1=x2$?

Comment: @gbox Just look at the question I asked, don't overthink it... If $g(y_1)=x_1$ what is $h(g(y_1))$? Don't look for a complicated answer....

Comment: $h(x1)$? sorry it is hard for me :(

Comment: @gbox Exactly.. So $h(x_1)=h(x_2)$ means $h(g(y_1))=h(g(y_2))$ and you know that $h\circ g$ is one to one...